# Encryption method for cuba platform

Tags: java, polymer, cuba-platform

Cuba has its own backend system to add users.
Now I need to write a user registration in the front-end.
The Cuba version I am using is 6.9
I know that this version of encryption is SHA1 ： https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.9/login.html
Now my question is ： I don't know how to set the encrypted password to the database.

I create an entity through the Metadata

```
User user = metadata.create(User.class);
user.setPassword(passWord);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that's the best option but I used the following code:

```
@Inject
protected PasswordEncryption passwordEncryption;

...

user.setPassword(passwordEncryption.getPasswordHash(user.getId(), password));
```

Comment: Same method used in official documentation for similar task https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.0/scriptingManagerMBean.html .

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to create html file with this code:

```
<div class="span6">
    <h3>Login</h3>

    <div th:if="${(param.error != null)}">
        <p>Invalid username / password</p>
    </div>

    <form id="f" name="f" method="POST" action="login">
        <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <div>
            <div>
                <label style="width: 80px" for="login">Login</label>
                <input type="text" id="login" name="login" value=""/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label style="width: 80px" for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and then Request it from Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        if (PortalSessionProvider.getUserSession().isAuthenticated()) {
            LoadContext l = new LoadContext(User.class);
            l.setQueryString("select u from sec$User u");
            model.addAttribute("users", dataService.loadList(l));
        }
        return "index";
    }
```